# Parse get image file data from url and save it as a Parse File

Tags: javascript, ajax, parse-platform, parse-server

I'm trying to get an image file using Ajax and then save it as a Parse File. I'm new to the process and this is what i've got so far:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        headers:{'Content-Type':'image/jpeg','X-Requested-With':'XMLHttpRequest'},
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {

            var name = "photo.jpg";
            var img = btoa(encodeURIComponent(data));

            var parseFile = new Parse.File(name, { base64: img });

            parseFile.save().then(function () {

                console.log('Saved parse file: ' + parseFile.url());

            }, function (error) {

                console.log("error: " + error.message);
            });
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

            console.log('error on uploadPhoto: ' + xhr + ' ' + ajaxOptions + ' ' + thrownError);
        }
    });
```

The File seems to be saved but all I get is an empty file. The Parse Docs says that we can use a base64-encoded String or an array of byte values.

What I'm I doing wrong, is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use a different approach using an XMLHttpRequest. Here's the code:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {

        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

            var reader = new window.FileReader();

            reader.readAsDataURL(this.response);

            reader.onloadend = function () {

                var name = "photo.jpg";

                var base64data = reader.result;

                var parseFile = new Parse.File(name, {base64: base64data});

                parseFile.save().then(function () {

                    console.log('Saved parse file: ' + parseFile.url());

                }, function (error) {

                    console.log("error: " + error.message);
                });
            }
        }
    };

    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.send();
```

Now the file is being saved correctly as a Parse File.